# Keycloak javascript - Store the keycloak object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keycloak

**Goal**

I am implementing Keycloak in an Angular2 project as my authentication service. For this, I use the javascript adapter.

**Problem**

I initialize the Keycloak object in the main.ts. A login is not directly required. During implementation, I faced a problem. When a page refresh occurred, a new Keycloak object is created which doesn't hold the original status (loginstatus, token etc.). 
I tried to save the Keycloak object to the localStorage. When I get (after JSON stringify and parse) the object, the object isn't recognized as a Keycloak object.

**Current workaround**

When logging in, I save an 'authenticated' boolean to the localStorage. I do a check in the main.ts if that 'authenticated' value is true. Then do a log in (after init) when a page refresh occurs. This is resulting in a double page refresh because the user gets redirected to Keycloak and is directly

**Question**

Is there a way to store the Keycloak object? Or is it possible to check if the user is already logged in when a new object is created?

Comment: Are you using the example from keycloak repository? I had similar problem under Firefox, did you try other browsers to confirm that's not browser related?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. The problem was not browser related. I already used parts of the Keycloak repository, now I picked more parts of this example. Do you know why a standalone loggedIn and logoutUrl variable is used in this example? The Keycloak object also stores this. My problem is solved by using 'check-sso' instead of 'login-required'. I thought that I already tried that.

Comment: Then you could add it as an answer and accept it ;) (When your rep will allow that)